# Java ResultSet empty but actually it shouldn't be

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc, resultset

I am trying to print a ResultSet, but it does not print anything. Can someone please tell me what is the problem ?
I am using Oracle 11g, JDK 1.7 and ojdbc6.jar.
Thanks in advance.
The code that I executed is below.

```
import java.sql.*;
public class database  {   
public static void main( String args[]){
    System.out.println("---Connecting to Oracle---");
    try{
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
    }
    catch( ClassNotFoundException e){
        System.out.println( e );
    }
    System.out.println("---JDBC Registered---");
    String URL = "jdbc:oracle:thin:admin/nihtij34@localhost:1521:XE";
    String user = "admin";
    String pwd = "nihtij34";
    try{
         Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(URL,user,pwd);
         Statement s = con.createStatement();
         s.executeQuery ("select * from seat  where doj= '1-01-2016' ");
         System.out.println("---QUERY EXECUTED---");
         ResultSet rs1 = s.getResultSet();
         while(rs1.next()){
             System.out.println( rs1.getString("tno"));
             System.out.println( rs1.getString("doj"));
             System.out.println( rs1.getString("sl"));
             System.out.println( rs1.getString("ac3"));
             System.out.println( rs1.getString("ac2"));
         }
         s.close();
         con.close();
    }
    catch(SQLException e){
        System.out.println(" NOT CONNECTED\n"+e);
    }           
} 
}
```

The output that I got was as follows:

```
---Connecting to Oracle---
---JDBC Registered---
---QUERY EXECUTED---
```

I tried the query in Oracle and it returned the following result.

```
SQL> select * from seat where doj='1-01-2016';

   TNO DOJ                SL        AC3        AC2
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
 11042 1-01-2016          10         10         10
 12163 1-01-2016          10         10         10
 12321 1-01-2016          10         10         10
 12322 1-01-2016          10         10         10
 12323 1-01-2016          10         10         10
 12324 1-01-2016          10         10         10
 12615 1-01-2016          10         10         10
 12616 1-01-2016          10         10         10
 12841 1-01-2016          10         10         10
 12842 1-01-2016          10         10         10
 12951 1-01-2016          10         10         10

   TNO DOJ                SL        AC3        AC2
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
 12952 1-01-2016          10         10         10

12 rows selected.
```

Can someone please tell me what is the problem ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: And if you try select * from seat  where doj= '1-01-2016' ?

Comment: You are definitely using the same db for both?

Comment: @UweAllner Yes, I am using the same database for both. Cross-checked it quite a few times.

Comment: @jarlh The sql query returned the same output. Updated the output.

Comment: have you tried formatting your date input with  **`to_date `**. How does it know what format of date you have chosen as input ?

Comment: @SacJn I have declared the datatypes of all columns as String. So, I guess formatting the date is not needed. I may be wrong.

Comment: Never, ever store dates in `varchar` columns. You should also read up on SQL injection and the use of `PreparedStatement`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Even Prepared Statements doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 5):

The line `s.executeQuery` already returns a ResultSet and you should use that, instead of subsequently calling `s.getResultSet()`. The [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#getResultSet()) on this also indicates that this second call will return null. I'm surprised that you are not getting a NullPointerException on `rs1.next()`.

Also, on a small side note, it is generally good practice to move your Connection and Statement variables outside the try-catch block and to close them in a `finally` block, or use the Java 7 try-with-resources construction.

Comment: Tried this. Didn't work. Got the same output.

 `ResultSet rs1 = s.executeQuery ("select * from seat  where doj= '1-01-2016' ");`

Comment: I agree, they lost original rs, My extra note: queries on DATE columns with string parameters are poor portable because of Locale

Answer (score -3):

Can you first extract data from the resultSet to variables and then output the variables?

For example:

```
String variable1 = rs1.getString("tno1")
......................................
String variable5 = rs1.getString("ac2")
System.out.println(variable1);
......................................
System.out.println(variable5);
```

Comment: How could that help, can you explain a little bit ?

Comment: That will extract item by item (row by row ) put them in variables and then display them. I think that will work if i understand your question properly.  However, that will only work for a few items. Otherwise, you can  SELECT * to display all the items.

Comment: by doing `rs.getString("colName")` itself, an implicit reference is being created. So assigning it to a new string variable should not make any difference. As he is doing exactly doing the same thing effectively. But you are unnecessarily creating so many string references. Along with your code would not offer any help, it will even degrade the performance